# Yeoman Grunt Bower - build not make right cdn

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower, cdn

I add angular-material and jquery-ui to my project via bower install.
Everything works fine until I build it.
In my index file (under dist folder) all cdn are fine except for the two added libraries.

```
......
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script> 
    <!-- endbower -->
     <!-- endbuild --> 
    <script src="scripts/scripts.bdd18021.js"></script>  
    <body ng-app="wwwApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl"> .....
```

if IWhat I'm doing wrong ?? run `grunt cdnify` the output is:

```
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs'
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'log4js'

Running "cdnify:dist" (cdnify) task
Going through dist/404.html, dist/index.html to update script refs
✔ bower_components/angular/angular.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-animate.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-aria.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-cookies.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-messages.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-resource.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-route.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-sanitize.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-touch.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular/angular.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-animate.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-aria.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-cookies.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-messages.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-resource.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-route.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-sanitize.min.js
✔ bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js changed to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.2/angular-touch.min.js

Done, without errors.
```

What I'm doing wrong ??
thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: Issue: [yeoman/generator-angular#266](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/266)